# externally setting variables that should be accessible within an object

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

Ok, so I know through closure I can do something like this:

```
var x,
    obj = {
            init: function() {
            x = 123;
          },

          func: function() {
            return x;
          }

    };

obj.init();
obj.func();
==> 123
```

However, I would like to externally be able to apply values for x (outside of the object, and later on)...  I thought that perhaps I could just do:

```
var obj = {
            init: function() {
              // do something nice here...
          },

            func: function() {
              return x;
          }
    };

var foo = {
            doIt: function() {

              var init = obj.init;
              var x;

              obj.init = function() {
                x = 456;
                init.apply(obj);
              }

              obj.init();
              obj.func();
          }
};

foo.doIt();
==> (error) x is not defined
```

However, it doesn't work..  Is this possible to do somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I exactly understand what your trying to do... is x supposed to be global?  Or is it supposed to be a variable in obj, or do you want it to be a private variable... I am unclear on what you want to do here.

Comment: x is supposed to be a variable in obj..  Ultimately I am trying to solve a problem of not being able to use 'this' to refer to the object itself when nested inside multiple functions.  I am always having to define 'self = this', inside my object's init method, and I was looking for a way to have this automated, so all my objects have a self variable by default that will refer to the object itself.  Here is an example of what I am really doing: http://pastie.org/1627048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create objects of your type using the `new` operator, and set the property on that object.

```
function Foo() {
    this.init = function() {
        this.x = -1;
    };

    this.func = function() {
        return this.x;
    };
}

var o = new Foo;
o.x = 941;
o.func(); // 941
o.x = 22;
o.func(); // 22
```